# Testing interface library

Tags: android, interface, integration-testing, android-library

I've created my own library with a method which takes Bitmap as input, runs a AsyncTask (to query a server about these images) and return a result with a callback interface.

I'd like to test this library by calling my method, passing it different kind of images, or null values, or even disabling internet and test its return.

**1) Is it possible/common practice to automate these kind of tests ?**

**If yes, can it be done in standalone in the testing folder of the library or do I need to create an app ?**

**2) Do you have a sample code for testing an interface callback within the test class ?**

I tried using Mockito but I can't quite get how this works.